# Clang lexer goes into SEGFAULT

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm trying to compile and use a Clang tool ([github](https://github.com/thedeadferryman/bindgen/tree/master/clang)). It compiles w/o any errors, but when I try to execute it, it goes into SEGFAULT. Debugger gives me the following stack trace:

```
clang::Preprocessor::RemovePragmaHandler(llvm::StringRef, clang::PragmaHandler*) 0x00007f8dd0da9599 <-- SEGFAULT here
clang::Parser::resetPragmaHandlers() 0x00007f8dd0a78c65
clang::Parser::~Parser() 0x00007f8dd0aa8260
clang::Parser::~Parser() 0x00007f8dd0aa86ca
clang::ParseAST(clang::Sema&, bool, bool) 0x00007f8dd09f39c8
clang::FrontendAction::Execute() 0x00007f8dd0ecd459
clang::CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction(clang::FrontendAction&) 0x00007f8dd0e814ee
clang::tooling::FrontendActionFactory::runInvocation(std::shared_ptr<clang::CompilerInvocation>, clang::FileManager*, std::shared_ptr<clang::PCHContainerOperations>, clang::DiagnosticConsumer*) 0x00007f8dd0b31e49
clang::tooling::ToolInvocation::runInvocation(char const*, clang::driver::Compilation*, std::shared_ptr<clang::CompilerInvocation>, std::shared_ptr<clang::PCHContainerOperations>) 0x00007f8dd0b2803c
clang::tooling::ToolInvocation::run() 0x00007f8dd0b2dafc
```

Clang distribution contains no debug symbols, and my machine stucks when I trying to compile LLVM and Clang with debug symbols on my own.

LLVM version is 9.0.0, `clang -v` gives the following:

```
clang version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

Comment: What is your question? Seems like this would be better suited to the appropriate issue tracker/reporting tool?